# Running a function on UI router angualr.js ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, routes

I currently have a UI router which is sending the user to other html files. Before routing the user I want to run a simple validate function. How can I go about doing this.

So when this state is clicked I want to run a function prior

```
.state('homeState', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
    })


function validate(event) {

    // body...
    alert('Validated');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
function validate(event) {

    // body...
    alert('Validated');

    // Than..

    $location.path("/home");

    }

    Also inject  '$location' in controller.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use resolve - see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve or $stateChangeStart - see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

Answer (score 0):

In html, instead of `ui-sref="homeState"` on element use `ng-click="validate()"`

And the code for *validate()* function in controller:

```
$scope.validate = function (){
  //body....
  alert('validated');
  $state.go('homeSate');
}
```

Don't forget to inject `$state` in controller.